# Why does `&*(&*d)` return address of "c" instead of address of "b"?

Tags: c++, pointers

I made some code, for understanding the concept/basic of pointer:

```
int a=1;
int *b=&a;
int **c = &b;
int ***d = &c;

cout << &*(&*d) << endl;
```

Why does `&*(&*d)` return address of "c" instead of address of "b"?

I've also tried code like `&*(&*(&*(&*(&*d))))`, but it keep return address of "c"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `&*` cancels each other out. `*` dereference `d` which gives the value of `c`. And then `&` gives the address of `c`, or the value of `d`.

Answer (score 3):

`&` and `*` cancel each other out.  If you want to dereference a pointer, you just need a `*`.  So, try `**d`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule: Use `*` to access/provide the value, use `&` to access/provide the address.

Answer (score 0):

`*` dereferences the pointer, and gives you the contents of where it points to.
& is basically addressof.

When used at the same point they cancel each other out, `&*d` is equivalent to d
if you want to print address of c you would need `*d`, for b you would need `**d`and for the data in a you would need `***d`.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is a variable, then `&*x` is not exactly equal to `x`. The former is an rvalue, while the latter is an lvalue. `*&x` on the other hand is always the same as `x`, because both expressions are lvalues.